# How do I highlight an HTML table column with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and have created a table in which I need columns grouped together. Is there any bootstrap options that I can use? I am willing to write my own CSS to do it, but I would rather not if there is a built in bootstrap way to do it.

For example, in the table below I would want the `Current` columns with one color background and the `New` columns to have another.

http://jsfiddle.net/75v7W/

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Current</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">New</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Fisrt Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Bauer</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>Bauer</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**: I have achieved something of what I am looking for using `colgroup` and, alas, custom CSS (though not very much) : http://jsfiddle.net/75v7W/4/

Comment: This is definitely not part of Bootstrap...

Comment: Not possible with just bootstrap, but this works assuming you don't want to add any additional markup to the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/75v7W/2/

Comment: @Prisoner - You don't need the `:first-child` declaration on the `tr` as one is `td` and one is `th`. Thats the way I'd go about it too, btw.

Comment: @JoshuaM I did think that after I posted it but thanks for posting it :)

Comment: @Prisoner You're more than welcome my good sir.

Comment: Does the `colgroup` tag buy my anything?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I achieved something of what I am looking for using `colgroup` and, alas, custom CSS (though not very much): http://jsfiddle.net/75v7W/4/

Note: For the `background-color`s below, I pulled from the success, error, etc. from the default colors in the `bootstrap.css`. If you have customized your bootstrap.css, these specific colors may not work for you.

**CSS**

```
colgroup col.success {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
colgroup col.error {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
colgroup col.warning {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
}
colgroup col.info {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}
```

**TABLE**

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col span="2" class="info">
        <col span="2" class="success">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Current</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">New</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Fisrt Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Bauer</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>Bauer</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This wont work for table-striped since every ntd(odd) tr gets overridden with its own background-color, and the tr element has more specificity than the col element. You will need to put a class on each <td>

Answer (score 15):

It is better, if it is possible use the bootstrap build-in css classes.

There is a built in way to hightlight a columns: https://jsfiddle.net/DanielKis/wp6bt229/

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="bg-success"></col>
    <col span="2" class="bg-info"></col>
    <col span="2" class="bg-danger"></col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="text-center bg-primary">Current</td>
      <td colspan="2" class="text-center">New</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Fisrt Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Johnny</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Bud</td>
      <td>Spencer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use

- `bg-primary`
- `bg-success`
- `bg-info`
- `bg-warning`
- `bg-danger`

Css classes to colorize your columns, cells, etc.