# Change background-color for one cell when hovering over another (Only css)

Tags: html, css

I have tried to read up on this and have gooten it to work before but can't get the hover-effect on one cell to change the background-color of another cell. Any suggestions?

CSS

```
.frontpagetabellskraddarsy {
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 15px; }

.frontpagecelltextskraddarsy {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.frontpagecellbildskraddarsy:hover .frontpagecelltextskraddarsy
{
    background-color: #289CDD;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="frontpagetabellskraddarsy" style="background-color: #f8f8f8;" cellspacing="20">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f8f8f8;" colspan="3" width="33%">[separator headline="h2" title="Skräddarsy din drömresa"]</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="location.href='http://www.baliexperten.se/skraddarsydd-resa/'" class="frontpagecellbildskraddarsy"><img alt="" src="http://media.baliexperten.se/2014/01/skraddarsypaket.png" class="frontpageresepaketbildskraddarsy"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td onclick="location.href='http://www.baliexperten.se/skraddarsydd-resa/'" class="frontpagecelltextskraddarsy"><strong>SKRÄDDARSY DIN DRÖMRESA </strong>
Vi hjälper dig att skräddarsy just din drömresa till Bali
           </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can u plz add the jsfiddle

Comment: You can't achieve this directly. You can try to use sibling selector (`+` and `~`) but you will hardcode html structure in CSS this way. Or you can try to highlight column (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967366/how-do-i-highlight-an-html-table-column-with-bootstrap). Simple js is a way to go though.

Comment: Alright. So maybe js is needed here then. Was hoping to be able to do it all using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
        #hoverDiv, #otherDiv {
            width: 200px;
            margin: 5px;
            float: left;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        #hoverDiv:hover + #otherDiv {
            background: #9ce;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="hoverDiv">
        Hover me!
    </div>

    <div id="otherDiv">
        My color will change :)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with arbitrary markup. You only option is to capture the hover on a tablerow `tr` and then animate either the adjacent row or one if it's cells via help of the `adjacent sibling combinator`:

```
tr:hover + tr td
```

[Quick and messy example fiddle with your code example](http://jsfiddle.net/exyd7/1/)

Hovering over a cell and achieve an effect for a cell of another row is not possible with CSS3! Selectors Level 4 have a proposal to [determine the Subject of a selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject), where you get more flexibility (but I think this case still would not work).

```
<tr id="one">
   <td></td>   // #one td:hover
</tr>
<tr id="two">
   <td></td>   // #two td
</tr>
```

One thinks something like `#one td:hover + #two td` might work, however, the context of the last element in the first part of the selector is considered. Once you are on cell level `#one td` you cannot take a step backwards to select the sibling `+ #two`.

`#one:hover + #two td` on the other hand works, because you capture the hover on `#one`, then traverse to the next row `+ #two` and then finally "select" the child element `td`.

Comment: Sry. Missed that you included a fiddle example. Okey. And if I want this function only in this specific table would the code then be .frontpagetabellskraddarsy tr:hover +tr td ?

Comment: Works fine. Thanks! Now, I would want the same effect on another table with several cells. Howeve, I would only want one specific cell to change background-color when hovering over another specific cell and not the whole row for example. Is this possible without js?

Comment: @user3201945 it's not possible if you want to trigger the hover on a cell, because you cannot "step backwards" with CSS. It only works with hover over the tablerow, bcause then you can select the adjacent row. Then you could just give a class or id to that cell and replace the `td` with that identifier.

Comment: Ok. But that would cause the hover effect to take place when hovering anywhere on that specified row, right? And not only hovering over the specific cell?

Comment: @user3201945 Yes. You cannot achieve the effect you want without css.